# Running a perl script on Windows

Tags: windows, perl

I have a script that run in Ubuntu but, I would like to run it in windows. I know how to execute it I just don't know what is wrong with my script to not make it run.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError);
use File::Find;

my @files = <C:\Windows\*.log>;

zip [ @files ] => 'Desktop/output.zip'
    or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";

unlink glob "'C:\Windows\*.log'";
print "The job is done\n";
```

Comment: I would say the string after `glob`. Why not reuse the same syntax you used for the `@files`? Possibly also the backslashes in the `<C:\...>` part. I cannot test on Windows.

Comment: What error does Perl throw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
my @files = glob 'C:/Windows/*.log';
```

and

```
unlink glob 'C:/Windows/*.log';
```

Calling `glob` explicitly is better than `<` `>`, and using `/` instead of `\` simplifies quoting.